# Shopify App Development need button on header

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

i am new to shopify app development.  i want to install an app that can add a button(simple drop-down) on header of shopify store. i can't find any help in docs.

- i made already made an app that opens in iframe and can add products via my app but could not find how i can add some html and script to my online store where i installed app.
- i read somewhere to add script tag to my app but i couldn't find any example or reference.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I used Google search engine with the keywords Shopify API script tags and this popped up.

https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/online-store/scripttag